# TypeORM MariaDB Primary Key as UUID

Tags: mysql, node.js, mariadb, typeorm

Having a really strange issue with TypeORM and MariaDB. I have two entities with UUIDs as the primary key. The Companies entity is working fine as it scaffolds the schema as CHAR but the users table is being instantiated as an auto increment INT.

User Entity

```
@Entity()
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column()
  firstname: string;

  @Column()
  lastname: string;

  @Column({ unique: true })
  email: string;

  @Column()
  password: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => Company, (company) => company.users)
  company: Company;
}
```

Companies Entity

```
@Entity()
export class Company {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @OneToMany(() => User, (user) => user.company)
  users: User[];
}
```

Config

```
const config: MysqlConnectionOptions = {
  type: 'mariadb',
  ....
  entities: ['dist/src/**/*.entity.js'],
  synchronize: true,
};
```

[Users Table Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iL5gg.png)

[Companies Table Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrJJu.png)

Find it really strange, is it because I'm using MariaDB instead of straight MySQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay looks like I fixed it, really odd one. Looks like something was cached incorrectly. Deleted dist folder and node modules. reinstalled and total recompile. Fixed...